# Core Data cannot batch process many records?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data

[This article](http://inessential.com/2010/02/26/on_switching_away_from_core_data) suggests that Core Data can only alter one record at a time, as opposed to directly querying a database using SQL. I am researching the "vs" between the two, and have read a lot of questions here on SO and elsewhere. But this is the first significant disadvantage I've seen relating to Core Data, and I'm a bit surprised that it would not support something as basic as batch record processing. Is this in fact correct?

Comment: That article is almost 3 years old. That's iOS 3 territory. Also, the reasoning still holds true: Core Data is an object persistence engine, not a database.

Comment: Try using a IOS6 core data tutorial….

Comment: I have looked at more recent iOS 5 + tutorials and cannot find examples of updating multiple "records" (managed objects) simultaneously in the way described in the article mentioned here. A single SQL statement can update many rows, whereas with Core Data it appears you must iterate and update individual items at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details in Brent's article linked here are correct and despite it's age, this is not an area of Core Data that has been updated in any meaningful way.

If you require a lot of batch operations in your persistence and if the lack of this capability has negative performance implications for the way data is used in your app, Core Data may not be the best choice, as it was for Brent.

As a side note, Brent's talked about this article a lot in interviews and podcasts since he wrote it and while it was an issue for him with the app in question, he's also talked about using Core Data in other apps since then - it's all about your app and how it's using it's data.